# Flutter geocoding

Tags: flutter, geocoding

I had the following code working with the geolocator.
Currently this functionality has been moved to the geocoding package.

I'm having problems getting if fixed and working hopefully some one can help me out!

```
class _ViewPostingPageState extends State<ViewPostingPage> {
  Posting _posting;
  LatLng _centerLatLong = LatLng(52.379189, 4.899431);
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _completer;

  void _calculateLatAndLng() async {
    _centerLatLong = LatLng(52.379189, 4.899431);
    Geolocator()
        .placemarkFromAddress(_posting.getFullAddress())
        .then((placemarks) {
      placemarks.forEach((placemark) {
        setState(() {
          _centerLatLong =
              LatLng(placemark.position.latitude, placemark.position.longitude);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Kind regads,
Robert

Comment: Refer to the package documentation https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding#api

Comment: Thanks! But I cann't get it to work. Hopefully you can help?

Answer (score 1):

[RobB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11464831/robb) Your code's equivalent using `geocoding` package:

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

class _ViewPostingPageState extends State<ViewPostingPage> {

  Posting _posting;
  LatLng _centerLatLong = LatLng(52.379189, 4.899431);
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _completer;
    
void _calculateLatAndLng() async {
    _centerLatLong = LatLng(52.379189, 4.899431);
    
    locationFromAddress(_posting.getFullAddress())
          .then((locations) {
           locations.forEach((location) {
            setState(() {
              _centerLatLong =
                  LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
            });
          });
        });
}
```